# List to archive old data on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, archive

I am needing to write a script, or find another way of listing directories on a drive where the folders haven't been accessed in the last 4 years and have the list outputted to a txt file.

Server is Windows 2012.

I hope my explanation isn't too vague.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how I can do this?